# Unable to run mongo express with docker compose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongo-express

This is my first post in node js and docker so bear with me. I am running a mongo and mongo express container with the docker-compose but mongo express is not running. When I run mongo and mongo express without docker-compose it works perfectly. So, I think I am having some issues in docker-compose or maybe node js code

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
```

**server.js**

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let fs = require('fs');
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
  });

app.get('/profile-picture', function (req, res) {
  let img = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "images/profile-1.jpg"));
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
  res.end(img, 'binary');
});

// use when starting application locally
let mongoUrlLocal = "mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017";

// use when starting application as docker container
let mongoUrlDocker = "mongodb://admin:password@mongodb";

// pass these options to mongo client connect request to avoid DeprecationWarning for current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine
let mongoClientOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

// "user-account" in demo with docker. "my-db" in demo with docker-compose
let databaseName = "my-db";

app.post('/update-profile', function (req, res) {
  let userObj = req.body;

  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrlLocal, mongoClientOptions, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let db = client.db(databaseName);
    userObj['userid'] = 1;

    let myquery = { userid: 1 };
    let newvalues = { $set: userObj };

    db.collection("users").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, {upsert: true}, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      client.close();
    });

  });
  // Send response
  res.send(userObj);
});

app.get('/get-profile', function (req, res) {
  let response = {};
  // Connect to the db
  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrlLocal, mongoClientOptions, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let db = client.db(databaseName);

    let myquery = { userid: 1 };

    db.collection("users").findOne(myquery, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      response = result;
      client.close();

      // Send response
      res.send(response ? response : {});
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("app listening on port 3000!");
});
```

If I run **docker ps** I can only see mongo is running

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                           NAMES
d20c4784d316   mongo     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   43 seconds ago   Up 38 seconds   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp   nodeapplications_mongodb_1
```

And when I run my docker-compose with the below command I see this log where I suspect an issue. Any help is appreciated

**docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up**

**Logs**

```
mongo-express_1  | Welcome to mongo-express
mongo-express_1  | ------------------------
mongo-express_1  | 
mongo-express_1  | 
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
mongo-express_1  | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017/"
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.3:27017
mongo-express_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
mongo-express_1  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
mongo-express_1  | }]
mongo-express_1  |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
mongo-express_1  |     at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:995:11
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
mongo-express_1  |     at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:280:5)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:310:7)
mongo-express_1  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
mongo-express_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
```

**As suggested by** @Blunderchips **Update 1**

**server.js**

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let fs = require('fs');
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let app = express();

const dbServer = process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER;
const dbPassword = process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD;
const dbUserName = process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME;
const dbPort = process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
  });

app.get('/profile-picture', function (req, res) {
  let img = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "images/profile-1.jpg"));
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
  res.end(img, 'binary');
});

// use when starting application locally
//let mongoUrlLocal = "mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017";

// use when starting application as docker container
let mongoUrlDocker = `mongodb://${dbUserName}:${dbPassword}@${dbServer}:${dbPort}`;//"mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017";//"mongodb://admin:password@mongodb";

// pass these options to mongo client connect request to avoid DeprecationWarning for current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine
let mongoClientOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

// "user-account" in demo with docker. "my-db" in demo with docker-compose
let databaseName = "my-db";

app.post('/update-profile', function (req, res) {
  let userObj = req.body;

  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrlDocker, mongoClientOptions, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let db = client.db(databaseName);
    userObj['userid'] = 1;

    let myquery = { userid: 1 };
    let newvalues = { $set: userObj };

    db.collection("users").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, {upsert: true}, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      client.close();
    });

  });
  // Send response
  res.send(userObj);
});

app.get('/get-profile', function (req, res) {
  let response = {};
  // Connect to the db
  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrlDocker, mongoClientOptions, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let db = client.db(databaseName);

    let myquery = { userid: 1 };

    db.collection("users").findOne(myquery, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      response = result;
      client.close();

      // Send response
      res.send(response ? response : {});
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("app listening on port 3000!");
});
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    links: 
        - mongodb:mongodb
```

I still can't see mongo express running

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
23428dc0c3a1   mongo     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp   nodeapplications_mongodb_1
```

**Logs**

```
mongo-express_1  | Welcome to mongo-express
mongo-express_1  | ------------------------
mongo-express_1  | 
mongo-express_1  | 
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
mongo-express_1  | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017/"
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.23.0.2:27017
mongo-express_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
mongo-express_1  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
mongo-express_1  | }]
mongo-express_1  |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
mongo-express_1  |     at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:995:11
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
mongo-express_1  |     at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:280:5)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:310:7)
mongo-express_1  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
mongo-express_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Update 2**

```
let express = require('express');
let path = require('path');
let fs = require('fs');
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "index.html"));
  });

app.get('/profile-picture', function (req, res) {
  let img = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "images/profile-1.jpg"));
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
  res.end(img, 'binary');
});

// use when starting application locally
//let mongoUrlLocal = "mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017";

// use when starting application as docker container
let mongoUrlDocker = "mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017";

// pass these options to mongo client connect request to avoid DeprecationWarning for current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine
let mongoClientOptions = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

// "user-account" in demo with docker. "my-db" in demo with docker-compose
let databaseName = "my-db";

app.post('/update-profile', function (req, res) {
  let userObj = req.body;

  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrlDocker, mongoClientOptions, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let db = client.db(databaseName);
    userObj['userid'] = 1;

    let myquery = { userid: 1 };
    let newvalues = { $set: userObj };

    db.collection("users").updateOne(myquery, newvalues, {upsert: true}, function(err, res) {
      if (err) throw err;
      client.close();
    });

  });
  // Send response
  res.send(userObj);
});

app.get('/get-profile', function (req, res) {
  let response = {};
  // Connect to the db
  MongoClient.connect(mongoUrlDocker, mongoClientOptions, function (err, client) {
    if (err) throw err;

    let db = client.db(databaseName);

    let myquery = { userid: 1 };

    db.collection("users").findOne(myquery, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      response = result;
      client.close();

      // Send response
      res.send(response ? response : {});
    });
  });
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("app listening on port 3000!");
});
```

**Update 3**

**docker-compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    links: 
        - mongodb:mongodb
    restart: on-failure
```

**Full Logs**

```
 mongo-express_1  | Welcome to mongo-express
mongo-express_1  | ------------------------
mongo-express_1  | 
mongo-express_1  | 
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:41:58.806+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22318,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down session sweeper thread"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:41:58.806+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22319,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down session sweeper thread"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:41:58.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22322,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down checkpoint thread"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:41:58.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22323,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Finished shutting down checkpoint thread"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:41:58.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795902, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Closing WiredTiger","attr":{"closeConfig":"leak_memory=true,"}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:41:58.810+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1625395318:810568][28:0x7f50eec9b700], close_ckpt: [WT_VERB_CHECKPOINT_PROGRESS] saving checkpoint snapshot min: 48, snapshot max: 48 snapshot count: 0, oldest timestamp: (0, 0) , meta checkpoint timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
mongo-express_1  | Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017/"
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.27.0.2:27017
mongo-express_1  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
mongo-express_1  |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
mongo-express_1  | }]
mongo-express_1  |     at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)
mongo-express_1  |     at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:995:11
mongo-express_1  |     at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
mongo-express_1  |     at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:280:5)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:310:7)
mongo-express_1  |     at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
mongo-express_1  |     at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
mongo-express_1  |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
mongo-express_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
mongo-express_1  | (node:7) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:42:00.871+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795901, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"WiredTiger closed","attr":{"durationMillis":2064}}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:42:00.871+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22279,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"shutdown: removing fs lock..."}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:42:00.872+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:42:00.873+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:42:00.873+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20626,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down full-time diagnostic data capture"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:42:00.878+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Now exiting"}
mongodb_1        | {"t":{"$date":"2021-07-04T10:42:00.879+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"SignalHandler","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":0}}
nodeapplications_mongo-express_1 exited with code 0
mongodb_1        | 
mongodb_1        | MongoDB init process complete; ready for start up.
```

Comment: Please read my answer again. Just copy/pasting the connection stuff at the bottom won't resolve the issue. If you with to go with that we are going to need to defined a port.

Comment: If you run `docker-compose up` and read the entire logs, are there MongoDB startup messages _after_ the mongo-express failure?  Does setting `mongo-express: { restart: on-failure }` help things along, or one of the more involved techniques described in [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)?

Comment: @DavidMaze I try to add restart: on-failure this in docker-compose under mongo express but no luck. Let me update my docker-compose & full logs.

Comment: The MongoDB `ready for start up` _after_ the mongo-express failure is the symptom I'd be looking for here.  If mongo-express exits with code 0 (success) even when it can't start up then you may need a stronger restart policy, maybe `restart: unless-stopped`.

Comment: @DavidMaze THanks now it is working. Please post it as an answer

Comment: Better to use: **depends_on: ["mongodb"]** since it is a **dependency issue**. The issue here is clearly that mongo-express did start while mongo was not ready yet, so it (mongo-express) failed to connect, and kept in that failed state.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As suggested by @David Maze by adding **restart: unless-stopped** it worked

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Comment: I'm doing the same course by techworkwithNana and experienced the same issue. I do not understand why the instructor did not get this error? How does adding restart: unless-stopped fix the issue?

Comment: Because its an older version when it used to work

Answer (score 2):

Adding `restart: unless-stopped` works, but that seems not the root cause, after read this - https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/, I think the issue is that mongo-express is depends on the mongo service, so ideally it should start after mongo is running, but seems there is no elegant solution for this issue, the `depends_on` option will help to reduce the problem but it can't solve it totally.

Check the limitation (or design) of `depends_on` option, https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on

Quote

> depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before
> starting web - only until they have been started. If you need to wait
> for a service to be ready, see Controlling startup order for more on
> this problem and strategies for solving it.

My final yaml file,

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    depends_on:
      - "mongodb"
    restart: unless-stopped
```

**Updates on 2023-06-23:**

> The solution for detecting the ready state of a service is to use the
> **condition** attribute with one of the following options

check: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/#control-startup

Answer (score 1):

Well, the issue here is clearly that mongo-express did start while mongo was not ready yet, so it (mongo-express) failed to connect, and kept in that failed state.

- using **restart: unless-stopped** is a solution but it is **not clean** for this purpose.

The way to go, is to add a dependency on mongo-express. It should start once mongo finished launching, and to achieve this use :

```
depends_on:
      - mongodb
```

Comment: That's not a solution. That doesn't wait until MongoDB is ready: it only waits until the container has started.

Answer (score 0):

The issues seem to be that you have configured the network. Within the express server, it is trying to connect to a Mongo instance running on its own localhost (being 127.0.0.1 of the container NOT your local machine). As there is no MongoDB instance running on your express service an `ECONNREFUSED` (Error Connection Refused) is thrown. What we need to do is place the DB container on a network accessible from the express service and connect to it. You can find more information at the [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) on networking with docker-compose.

What I find the easiest to do in this case, particularly for local development is to 'link' to two services together as shown below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
    links: 
        - mongodb:mongodb
```

Then change `mongoUrlLocal` to `mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017`. Please check out the [documentation here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links) for more information. In effect, this creates a little pseudo DNS record within the `mongo-express` services that points at the `mongodb` service so whenever you try to connect to an address of "mongodb" you are connecting to the container that is running your database. Please note that this will only work for linked services so you can't connect to "mongodb" from your local machine.

In addition what I recommended you do I have environment variables for your database connection. At the moment I see you have `ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER` which is not used, `mongoUrlLocal` and `mongoUrlDocker`. I think it may be better to pull the connection string information from `process.env` then pass the environment variables, as you already, from your docker-compose file.

Something like this for example:

```
const dbServer = process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER;
const dbPassword = process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD;
const dbUserName = process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME;
const dbPort = process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT;

let mongoUrl = `mongodb://${dbUserName}:${dbPassword}@${dbServer}:${dbPort}`;
```

Comment: I apply the solution you suggested and updated my question but it is not working for me

Comment: What is your MongoDB URL?

Comment: Please note the connection string at the bottom was an example of what could be done. The most important thing is linking the containers.

Comment: How can i get the MongoDb URL?

Comment: The MongoDb URL is the URL you use to connect to your database.

Copy/paste the docker-compose file, set the database then set the database connection string to "mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017"
Please read my answer carefully again or look at the comments I posted on the question(:

Comment: I didn't get it. I have already pasted my docker-compose file. And the database I have set  from this line let databaseName = "my-db"; And if my mongo-exppress works then the same I will create it from there

Comment: I have updated the line let mongoUrlDocker = "mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017";

Comment: `links:` are an obsolete setting from first-generation Docker networking; they're unnecessary on present-day Docker, and the Compose file shouldn't need to be changed (in fact, the error message from the original question shows the client is resolving the `mongodb` host name successfully).  The environment-variable configuration is good advice but it's probably not the core problem here.

Comment: for me both links: - mongodb:mongodb and restart: unless-stopped solution worked. Using links option mongo-express connects to mongodb immediately. Like Aniket mentioned without docker compose both containers (mongodb & mongo-express) work fine. Its only when using docker compose to build the containers, mongo-express does not initialise.